# How can I check for existing "li" items before appending?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to insert a new `<li>` item in the list, but only if this item does not exist already. For example:

```
<ul id="myList">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

That is, "Item 7" should insert, but not "Item 1". I´m going crazy over statements like these:

1. `var ListItems = $('#myList li').find('Something');`
2. `var ListItems = $('#myList li').html() == 'something';`
3. ```
   var exist = $('#myList li').each(){
       if($(this).html == 'something')
           return false;
   });
   ```

These pieces of code are only to check if `<li>` items exist, not to insert in the list. I'm assuming that these options are crazy but I'm trying to learn.

What is the right way? Any advice or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited to avoid false positives**

This will check the elements one by one and the text contained inside must match exactly the text provided.

```
var  itemName = 'Item 2';
var itemFound = false;

$('#myList li').each( function () {

    if ( $(this).text() === itemName )
    {
        itemFound = true;
    }

});

if ( itemFound == true )
{
    alert( 'item already present' );
}
else
{
    alert( 'item not present' );
    // add item here
}
```

[check example here](http://jsfiddle.net/HhHYC/)

Comment: If a list contains an item like "Item 1" if I check something like "Item" or "ite" returns: already exist. The same to example 1. Any advice to strictest comparison?

Comment: Edited with a solution to avoid false positives.

Comment: Thanks sososo much,
now works right :).I can´t vote+ the answer because my reputation is low by the moment :P

Comment: @Marcos come back later then ;) by the way there are many ways you can improve the above script, for example by adding return false; immediately after the item has been found (to avoid useless checks), using pure javascript methods, etc... but it's a good start.

Comment: Sure, always read answers but now need to ask for one day begin to answer. I´m using return false now, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if(!$('#myList li:contains("Text here")').length) {
    // Insert your new li
}
```

It uses the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to find any `li` elements that contain `Text here`.

jQuery here returns an array, so we can use `.length` on it. If the length returned is zero, then we insert our new `li` as there are no existing elements containing the text given.

Comment: Technically jQuery isn't returning an array, it's returning a jQuery object which also has a `.length` property.

Comment: Wow, so easy!. Works great.
I´m so happy to learn day by day :) 
Thanks so much.

Comment: This is vulnerable to false positives since it matches against elements containing the text, not having exactly that text. For example, if you try to add "Item 2" and "Item 23" already exists, this will return a false positive.

Comment: @phloopy do you know how is the best way to strictest comparison?

Comment: @mblase75 Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Marcos The accepted answer by Jose Faeti compares the full text and is case-sensitive, so that should do the trick.